# Reading DATE field from Oracle with JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm using an Oracle server, which I don't control, in another time zone (US, Central).  There is a table with a DATE column, which gets a default value of SYSDATE when things are inserted (I.e., the column is always set with the system's time, without the programmer needing to set it explicitly).

I'm in a different time zone (US, East Coast).  How do I read this column with JDBC and get an Epoch/UTC time?

When I call `getTimestamp().getTime()` (on the ResultSet), I get the time converted to local time.  That is, if something was inserted at 10 am on the server, it is 11 am here (and 4 pm in UTC).  When I call `getTimestamp().getTime()` I get an epoch of 10 am local time (which is 3 pm UTC).

I have a partial answer.

```
Calendar sqlServerCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
long t = rs.getTimestamp("timestampcolumn", sqlServerCalendar).getTime();
```

This is not ideal, because I have to specify the server's time zone (which I'd move into settings).  But it does seem to return the answer I want.  Is there a way I can query the server's time zone at run-time, rather than needing a setting?  Or, is there a better way to do this?  I would prefer a solution to not have to know (via hard-coded values, or settings) which time zone it or the server are in (so it will work unmodified if run in different time zones, and/or if the server moves).

Comment: what dateformat pattern did you use for checking the time in your output? Make sure to set timezone (to utc) in that code

Comment: I'm getting the number as a long (returned by getTime(), and copying that to www.epochconverter.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the JVM parameter `-Duser.timezone` such as `java -Duser.timezone=GMT` and that should do the trick. But again one important thing to keep in mind about setting the timezone for the entire JVM is that it affects everything.

If you just need to set only for time zones when retrieving date, time or timestamp objects. you can do it like

```
Calendar mycal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

then on the result set

```
Date correctDate = resultset.getDate("Timestampcolumn",mycal);
```

I believe you should also be able to set the timezone using `TimeZone.setDefault()` as well.

Comment: This looks like it made getTimestamp().getTime() return an epoch for 10 am UTC, which is also not correct.